# How to update query using SQLite with cast as int

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having an error on using `update` with using `cast (column1 as int)` query. I need a `VARCHAR` column for our data seurity (encrypting our data). I can't find an answer on google. Please help me. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Typically you cast the right hand side of an assignment, not the left hand side.  What is the type/affinity of the `is_send` column?

Comment: its a VARCHAR column

Comment: I believe the reason for the syntax error is because you are trying to say that a column is not a column i.e. you are casting it to a literal value and thus it cannot then be a column name. So SQLite sees it as syntactically wrong as you are effectively saying update a value which is not stored anywhere in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `column1` were declared as `VARCHAR`, then most likely its affinity means that the actual underlying storage class in SQLite is `TEXT`.  If you have the need to store integers, then you should have declared this column as `INT` or `INTEGER`.  That being said, the following update might work:

```
UPDATE tickets SET is_send = 1;
```

This would work if SQLite can do the conversion from integer to string for you.  If not, then use:

```
UPDATE tickets SET is_send = '1';
```

Or, if you want to cast, then use:

```
UPDATE tickets SET is_send = CAST('1' AS TEXT);
```

In general, if you have the need to store numbers, use a number column, and vice-versa for text.

Comment: I understand. but our required column for all of our column is `VARCHAR`. this is done because all of our data were encrypted by using `VARCHAR`

Comment: @MikeGorospe Then cast the integer into text before you try to insert/update.  If the column stores, text, then it's storing text, right?